# TypeError: CrossEntropyLoss.forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'weight'

Tags: pytorch, loss

I am getting this error:

```
  File "/nitorch/trainer.py", line 110, in __init__
    nn.CrossEntropyLoss(outputs, labels, weight = weights)
  File "/home/gonzalo/miniconda3/envs/cnn2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1110, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
TypeError: CrossEntropyLoss.forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'weight'
```

I am trying to get the loss with a manual rescaling weight given to each class using torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss:
`loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(outputs, labels, weight = weights)`
where weights is a tensor of weights with the same length as outputs and labels.

The documentation of the torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss says it accepts weights to rescale classes
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html

What could be happening?

Answer (score 2):

You first need to create an instance of `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` with the class weights and then call it with the output and labels:

```py
loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=weights)
output = loss(outputs, labels)
```

All [pytorch docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) contain examples at the bottom.